# How to generate variation identifier and bucket in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R.

```
ID     First Value    End Value    First Grade     Final Grade
I-1    150000         5000         100             -80
I-2    150000         5000         100             80
I-3    NA             NA           NA              NA
I-4    1000           1500         75            100
```

By using the above dataframe, I want to create the following column based on certain condition.

- `Value Var` - If End Value is is higher than first value then `High`, If end Value is lower than first value then `Low` if end and first value are same then `No Diff` and If end and first value has `NA` then `Outlier`.
- `Grade Var` - The above logic to be followed for this as well.
- `Value % Diff` - To derive this we need to substract first value from end value divided by first value
- `Grade % Diff` - The above logic to be followed for this as well

Required Output<-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test each condition within `case_when` and assign values to new column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ValueVar = case_when(EndValue > FirstValue ~ 'High', 
                              EndValue < FirstValue ~ 'Low', 
                              EndValue == FirstValue ~ 'No diff', 
                              TRUE ~ 'Outlier'), 
         GradeVar = case_when(FinalGrade > FirstGrade ~ 'High', 
                              FinalGrade < FirstGrade ~ 'Low', 
                              FinalGrade == FirstGrade ~ 'No diff', 
                              TRUE ~ 'Outlier'), 
         ValueDiff = (EndValue - FirstValue)/FirstValue * 100, 
         GradeDiff = (FinalGrade - FirstGrade)/FirstGrade * 100, 
         across(ends_with('Diff'), ~case_when(is.na(.) ~ 'Outlier', 
                                              TRUE ~ paste0(round(., 2), '%'))))

#   ID FirstValue EndValue FirstGrade FinalGrade ValueVar GradeVar ValueDiff GradeDiff
#1 I-1     150000     5000        100        -80      Low      Low   -96.67%     -180%
#2 I-2     150000     5000        100         80      Low      Low   -96.67%      -20%
#3 I-3         NA       NA         NA         NA  Outlier  Outlier   Outlier   Outlier
#4 I-4       1000     1500         75        100     High     High       50%    33.33%
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("I-1", "I-2", "I-3", "I-4"), FirstValue = c(150000L, 
150000L, NA, 1000L), EndValue = c(5000L, 5000L, NA, 1500L), FirstGrade = c(100L, 
100L, NA, 75L), FinalGrade = c(-80L, 80L, NA, 100L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```